# How to use Site Type to create the new site but not inherit the domain setting

Tags: web8, topology-manager, site-types

When I create a new site based on site type, I can only add the sub path for the new site URL and have to inherit the site type's domain setting.

For example, site type related topology manager URL setting is http://siteexample.com. When create another site based on this site type, the URL has to be:  http://siteexample.com/[sub_path]. Only the sub path can be change, but the domain has to be http://siteexample.com.

Besides manually run powerscript to delete the setting and redo it again for the new site, any other way can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the Site Wizard.

Note that the idea of the Site Wizard is that Business Users can create new Sites without IT involvement. By using a single domain in combination with a Web App that can deal with multiple mappings (with distinct Relative URLs or "sub paths") such as DXA, this is really feasible.

Creating new domains (incl. DNS entries) typically requires IT involvement anyways.